# I can't get the Boolean modifier to work

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make the charger port in the phone model.
I dont't know how to make rhe boolean[image: my 3D modeling] modifier work  I have no idea how to fix it. It would be nice if someone could assist me.

Comment: You should first apply solidifier modify, then apply Boolean and delete the cube.

Comment: Thank u for the help.